# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: about:neterror?

Tags: python, django, selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver

I'm using [bok_choy](https://bok-choy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/>) which uses Selenium in order to write acceptance tests. The tests are working fine with chromedriver/geckodriver on a local machine but it doesn't work with Selenium Images inside docker container. Gives the following error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_result_page (__main__.TestPolls)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bok_choy/page_object.py", line 329, in visit
    self.browser.get(self.url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=nssFailure2&u=https%3A//demo.app%3A8000/polls/&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=%20


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app/tests/test_polls.py", line 35, in test_result_page
    self.polls_index_page.visit().click_question('question1')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bok_choy/page_object.py", line 332, in visit
    raise PageLoadError(u"Could not load page '{!r}' at URL '{}'".format(
bok_choy.page_object.PageLoadError: Message: Could not load page '<pages.PollsIndexPage object at 0x7f19190eed00>' at URL 'http://demo.app:8000/polls/'


======================================================================
ERROR: test_vote_again (__main__.TestPolls)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bok_choy/page_object.py", line 329, in visit
    self.browser.get(self.url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=nssFailure2&u=https%3A//demo.app%3A8000/polls/&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=%20


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app/tests/test_polls.py", line 42, in test_vote_again
    self.polls_index_page.visit().click_question('question1')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bok_choy/page_object.py", line 332, in visit
    raise PageLoadError(u"Could not load page '{!r}' at URL '{}'".format(
bok_choy.page_object.PageLoadError: Message: Could not load page '<pages.PollsIndexPage object at 0x7f1918f24100>' at URL 'http://demo.app:8000/polls/'
```

I used `python app/tests/test_polls.py` to run the tests inside `demo.app` container.

my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:latest

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app
COPY ./app /app

ENV SELENIUM_BROWSER=firefox
ENV SELENIUM_HOST=selenium-hub
ENV SELENIUM_PORT=4444
```

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    container_name: demo.app
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
      - /etc/hosts:/etc/hosts
    command: >
      sh -c "python app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
      && python test_polls.py"
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:3.141.59-yttrium
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
  chrome:
    container_name: demo.chrome
    image: selenium/node-chrome:3.141.59-yttrium
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444
  firefox:
    container_name: demo.firefox
    image: selenium/node-firefox:3.141.59-yttrium
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444
```

Pages.py:

```
from bok_choy.page_object import PageObject


class PollsIndexPage(PageObject):
    url = 'http://demo.app:8000/polls/'

    def is_browser_on_page(self):
        return self.q(css='.questions').is_present()

    def click_question(self, question):
        self.q(css='#{} a'.format(question)).click()
        PollsDetailPage(self.browser).wait_for_page()


class PollsDetailPage(PageObject):
    url = None

    def is_browser_on_page(self):
        return self.q(css='input#vote').is_present()

    def select_choice(self, choice):
        self.q(css='#{}'.format(choice)).click()

    def vote(self):
        self.q(css='input#vote').click()
        PollsResultPage(self.browser).wait_for_page()

    def vote_a_question(self, choice):
        self.select_choice(choice)
        self.vote()

    @property
    def title(self):
        return self.q(css='h1').text[0]

    @property
    def vote_error(self):
        return self.q(css='#error strong').text[0]


class PollsResultPage(PageObject):
    url = None

    def is_browser_on_page(self):
        return self.q(css='#vote_again').is_present()

    def vote_again(self):
        self.q(css='#vote_again').click()
        PollsDetailPage(self.browser).wait_for_page()
```

test_polls.py:

```
import unittest

from bok_choy.web_app_test import WebAppTest

from pages import PollsIndexPage, PollsDetailPage, PollsResultPage


class TestPolls(WebAppTest):
    def setUp(self):
        """
        Instantiate the page objects.
        """
        super(TestPolls, self).setUp()
        self.polls_index_page = PollsIndexPage(self.browser)
        self.polls_detail_page = PollsDetailPage(self.browser)
        self.polls_result_page = PollsResultPage(self.browser)

    def test_page_existence(self):
        """
        Make sure that the page is accessible.
        """
        self.polls_index_page.visit()

    def test_detail_page(self):
        """
        Check if the detail page opens after clicking a question
        """
        self.polls_index_page.visit().click_question('question1')
        assert "What's up?" == self.polls_detail_page.title

    def test_result_page(self):
        """
        Check if the result page opens after voting a question
        """
        self.polls_index_page.visit().click_question('question1')
        self.polls_detail_page.vote_a_question('choice1')

    def test_vote_again(self):
        """
        Check vote_again option in results page
        """
        self.polls_index_page.visit().click_question('question1')
        self.polls_detail_page.vote_a_question('choice1')
        self.polls_result_page.vote_again()
        self.polls_detail_page.vote_a_question('choice2')

    def test_invalid_vote(self):
        """
        make sure that an error message is shown when no choice is selecteddadad
        """
        self.polls_index_page.visit().click_question('question1')
        self.polls_detail_page.q(css='input#vote').click()
        assert "You didn't select a choice." == self.polls_detail_page.vote_error


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```